# What do you mean by Communication Network?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, phrasing, compound-words

In the following concept, what do you mean by Communication Network?

There is an association (an inter-continental one) in which each member participates in building relation among its member through social and media network. The association called themselves **Vilalgename** (this is their village name) **Communication Network**.  Can the name be the right one in this situation. What exactly is the meaning of Communication in this context?

Comment: @Lawrence, I updated the question. Please do check it.

Comment: Thanks for updating. If all the association does is help its members get in touch with one another, then *communication* should be understood in the usual way - members 'talking/chatting/etc' to one another. See definition 1.3 in [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/communication). Whether the other definitions there make sense depends on the actual activities of the association - the association should be able to tell you. After all, they call themselves a "Communication Network". :)

Comment: @Lawrence, Thanks for the insight. The meaning in the context is a bit awkward to me, A village name followed by a compound noun `communication network` seems to me a business enterprise involved in providing network materials.  What do you suggest?

Comment: It can mean pretty much anything.

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks. I am not a native speaker. Please can you give an example where Village Name+Communication+Network is used?

Comment: Anything with "communication" (and "network") in the name sounds like it is involved with, well, you know, communication. Exactly how they are involved may not be specified by the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the relevant definitions:

> **communication** *noun*
> 1.3 Social contact.
> ‘she gave him some hope of her return, or at least of their future communication’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/communication)
>
> **network** *noun*
> 2.2 A group of people who exchange information and contacts for professional or social purposes.
> ‘a support network’
> ‘These were people with an extensive network of social contacts.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/network)

If the business owned telecommunication infrastructure, it would be sensible to interpret *communication network* in the physical sense.

But for an association whose primary purpose is to put people in touch with each other, the phrase *communication network* should be understood in the sense of **linking a group of people together to facilitate members interacting with one another**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When a progressive noun like a village name appears before `communication network`, doesn't it look like something else when one does not know it is an association?

Comment: @AmanfromSilchar You're welcome. Business names don't necessarily mean what they 'say' - especially when the words chosen can mean different things. For example, Apple Inc doesn't sell fruit, IBM (International Business Machines) doesn't primarily sell machines, and Microsoft isn't a particularly small company. If you want to know what a business does, you're well advised to ask them.